Getting BER Value (exp - float) from Hex value
I Have an HEX value of 0x4995
which I know it is converted to this value: 4.050000e-13 (BER - Bit Error Rate)(float),
I need help to understand the algorithm for this conversion,
from little research I made I know that i need to extract from the HEX value the positive/negative value, and then the exp value of the result and also something called Mantissa.
Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

How did you conclude this hex value can be converted to this other value?  BER is (bit errors) / (bits transferred).  Not sure how this hex value relates to that.  Mantissa is the part of a logarithm that follows the decimal point.

Thanks for your response, I just posted the solution for my question, thanks again !.

After lots of research from the internet, I found the whole solution.
Apparently I had to convert from Hex value to something called IEEE 754 floating-point.
The Hex value of 0x4995 is converted to the required BER value by Exponential parameter and mantissa parameter.
Mantissa value = 0x4995 AND 0x7FF (Here the Mantissa is 11 bit length from the original value according to the protocol), which gives us value of 405.
Exp value = (0x4995 >> 11)x(0x1F) (Shift right 11 bits anded with 0x1f to get the rest 5 bits which represents the Exp value), this gives us value of 9.
EXP Value which is now far away 9 decimal points from :  1e-24 ( 1e-24 is the lowest Exp parameter of that protocol).
BER result = Mantissa* Exp value  = 405 * 1e-15 = 4.05e-13.
I'm not sure all I wrote here is accurate, but as long as I found the solution I'm pretty happy with it.
If someone can correct what I wrote or give more accurate info, that will be great.
I hope this will support other forum members.
